# I'm trying to make custom formatting that highlights when a number is more than and less than a specific formula

Tags: excel, google-docs, conditional-formatting, doc

I work for a brokerage and we profit in the margin.  In order to keep these margins at the forefront of everyones mind we want to format it so that if the bid is over our 15% goal it highlights in order to make the broker aware he is outside of the target zone.

In the example below the rate we are charging is $1,000.00 and we want to find a provider for $850.00 or less in order to meet margin.  At $851.00 and higher I have the amounts being highlighted, I managed this by putting =sum(A12*0.85) in F and put a conditional formatting into E for =E14>F14, I then hide F to make it look clean.

I am by no means an experienced Docs user so I'm hoping I'm missing an easy fix but my problems are:

1. That I need to manually enter a lot of this (thousand of lines, always need more), inserting new lines at the bottom of that E14:E23 string does not carry over the F function and causes even a blank cell to highlight orange since the F cell is blank.
2. I need to have this same process done for many loads, this is one load, the next one might be $2,000.00 and I don't want to manually have to do each one, a simple copy paste method is beyond my ability to figure out.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In column E for example.

Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula

```
=IF(AND(A1<>"",E1<>"",E1>=A1*0.85),1,0)
```

Comment: I changed the "A1" in that formula to "A12" and "E1" to "E14", pasted it in, so far it will only highlight the first cell in the string I want to have this formatting, none of the rest.  Do I need to use some $ signs?  Thanks for the help.